# What does the Redis 'redis.publish()' method do?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

What does **`redis.publish();`** **method** do in the following module.

**`redis.publish("WordCountTopology", exclamatedWord.toString() + "|" + Long.toString(count));`**

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple)
    {
      String word = tuple.getString(0);

      StringBuilder exclamatedWord = new StringBuilder();
      exclamatedWord.append(word).append("!!!");

      _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(exclamatedWord.toString()));

      long count = 30;
      redis.publish("WordCountTopology", exclamatedWord.toString() + "|" + Long.toString(count));
    }
```

Comment: Good read: [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/redis-pub-sub-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It publishes the string (ExclamatedWord + "|30") to a Redis channel called `WordCountTopology` - subscribers to that channel will get the message once `redis.publish` executes.

For more information about Redis' Pub/Sub see: http://redis.io/topics/pubsub